# Grep command in linux

Tags: linux, sorting, grep

I need a little help to write a grep command in a single line to get first 15 files along with Size of the file in MB and sort by last modified time stamp.

if I execute below command

```
grep -il "SmapleString" *.log| xargs -t ls -ltr
```

**Result:**

```
-rw-r--r--    1 Text1 Text2     5432278 27 mar 15:22 SampleFile.log
```

**My Result:**

```
grep -il "SmapleString" *.log| xargs -t ls -ltr| tr -s ' ' | cut -d' '  -f5-9|tail -r|head -15
```

5432278 27 mar 13:44 SampleFile.log

**Required Output:**

```
27 mar 13:44 SampleFile.log 5MB
```

OR

```
5MB 27 mar 13:44 SampleFile.log
```

please post your comments

Comment: You can use `ls -h` to get human-readable file sizes.

Comment: ls - h i already tried and its not working, its showing below error:  It is not a recognized badge: h

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> `ls -l -h -t | head -n 5`
>   `-t`  sort by modification time, newest first

Comment: ls -l -h -t | head -n 5 -t
ls: No es un distintivo reconocido: h                                                                   "h" command is not working i always getting error when i use h command

Comment: Can you please share your Linux distro and version?

Comment: grep -il "SampleString" *.log| xargs -t ls -ltr |awk '{$5=sprintf($5/1024^2)} 1'                                            This is worked :)

Comment: Great! You can post your answer, for somebody else comes looking for it.